# Django - model Inheritance - store that shares a common stock

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I'm making a store (for the lols), i want to make it so that if i have an item i have a stock and possible multiple listings of that item.

So basically i want to have some properties like:
How many is left,
Name,
weight, and so on

But then i want some other properties to be different like the price.
So the idea is that i can have different listings like: 1 car for 200 dollars and 2 cars for 175 dollars. But i want them to have the same stock pool so when someone purchases the item they both get updated.

I can't find any convenient way of doing this in django, it would seem i need some kind of mix between proxy and multi table inheritance.

So my question is did i missunderstand the whole concept of inheritance (e.g is this possible with inheritance) in django, do i have to find another way of doing this, maybe it isn't possible or just too overkill to implement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you go about modelling it in the database ?

This will definitely help you reasoning about your django model.

I think, you will need to have something like:

```
[Products]---One to many---> [ProductPrices]
 ProductId                    ProductId
 Name                         NumberOfItems
 Description                  Price
 NumberInInventory
```

And, when you process an order (not shown in my crappy table representation), you simply deduct the number in inventory from the number of items, based on product prices.

This is the simplest possible thing that would solve the problem as described. If you need additional properties, that are specific to categories of products, for instance, computer specs (RAM, HDD space, processor and such), then table/model inheritance makes sense.

If your characteristics are common to all products, they belong to the product table.

Comment: Figured i would have to do something like this but wanted to make sure i didn't missunderstand the inheritance thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [django oscar](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar).I think it will serve your purpose.It has all the features that you need for building an e-commerce website.